# Performance issues with rendering in datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to render around 2500 rows with sorting disabled and "bDeferRender": true. It's taking around 40s in chrome(v27). I am using Datatables 1.9 and jquery 2. Any suggestions?

Datatable `settings` for my datatable:

```
var oSettings = {
    'bDestroy': true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    'iDisplayLength': 10,
    'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
    'sDom': '<"top"i> T<"clear">lfrtip',
    'sPageButtonActive': "paginate_active",
    'sPageButtonStaticDisabled': "paginate_button",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "Futher Filter Search results:",
        "sInfo": "Got a total of _TOTAL_ results to show (_START_ to _END_)",
        "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select>' +
                '<option value="5">5</option>' +
                '<option value="10">10</option>' +
                '<option value="15">15</option>' +
                '<option value="20">20</option>' +
                '<option value="25">25</option>' +
                '</select> results'
    },
    "bSort": false
};
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the JavaScript and not with the network?  See how fast your content gets delivered by opening the developer tools, going to the Network tab, then reloading the page.  This will show you if any of your requests are taking a super long time.  If not, then you're right, it's probably the JavaScript.  In that case, you should paginate the table rows and deliver the pages separately with Ajax

Comment: @NathanWallace  the datatable is not created on page load. It is created after user's action like button click.

I am calculating the time for datatable creation/rendering using javascript functions and I can see the duration for datatable creation is around 35-40 sec.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quick guess: you are using fnAddData like this `oTable.fnAddData(cells)`, once for each row.  This will cause the DataTable to redraw after each addition.  Add a second parameter, `false`, e.g., `oTable.fnAddData(cells,false)`.  Then after your loop, call `oTable.fnDraw()`.  This will redraw only once instead of 2500 times.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V2Kdz/

Click the "Populate" button to populate the table.

Line 12 is:

```
var ai = t.fnAddData(cells,false);
```

With the redraw parameter false, the table draws in under one second (on my mid-2011 Mac Air).  If you set the redraw parameter to true (or remove it, as the default is true), it takes over one minute.

Comment: Thank you. fnAddData works great. I am able to load tree within a sec or two.

Comment: **Home run for me!**  After a while trying to figure out if it was even possible to optimize my ~3000 row datatable, this did the trick.  Load time decreased instantly from ~3 minutes to ~3 seconds.  (WHY doesn't the `bDeferRender` flag work?  Come to think of it, it's because after each row is added, there's no way for the DataTable to know you are going to add more.)