# datatables slow data loading

Tags: javascript, datatables, crossfilter

I'm trying use [crossfilter](https://github.com/square/crossfilter) with datatables, but datatables loading data is very slow (`fnAddData()`). It takes about 1s per 1000 rows. Crossfilter sends data to datatables in array with 1-5000 rows. For 5000 rows table is rendered about 5 seconds. Is it possible to load data to datatables some faster way?

Note:

Comment: Do you really need 5000 rows! You should really look at populating datatables from an Ajax source. http://datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: Try fnAddData(cells, false).  Then call fnRedraw when it's all done.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923784/performance-issues-with-rendering-in-datatables/16939760#16939760

Comment: @BenThurley May be don't. But I want to see how many rows there are and I have all data loaded for a filtering by crossfilter.

Comment: @BumptiousQBangwhistle: Yes, it is possible, but user has to still wait for rendering the table.

Comment: Have you looked at these: https://www.datatables.net/usage/features#bSortClasses  and https://www.datatables.net/usage/features#bDeferRender

Comment: @Meph- you don't need to load all rows for this. You return the total count in the ajax response. Datatables uses this info to display the correct number of pages. Each time you click for a new page or do a sort or filter it goes back to the server to get the data. The link should explain all. Personally I wouldn't send more than 100 rows to the client in one request, let alone 5000.

Comment: Take a look at this blog article I wrote a while ago. It should give you some ideas. http://bthurley.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/initialising-datatables-with-twitter-bootstrap-and-spring-mvc-ajax/

Comment: Regardless how fast you insert the rows, you still need to wait for DataTables rendering the table. This is a factor 1000 or something like that. With other words, you gain very, very little by focusing on how fast you can insert the rows. Focus on pagination and / or load in the background instead - or the advices above.